# how to get this value from json?

Tags: php, json

I have request like this:

```
{
    "type":"message_new",
    "object":
    {
        "id":1,
        "date":1514645830,
        "out":0,
        "user_id":217185147,
        "read_state":0,
        "title":"",
        "body":"123"
    },
    "group_id":158575966
}
```

so, i need to get "body" from "object" to usual variable, for example $text

P.S. sorry for my bad english

Comment: You can do this after json_decode()

Comment: yeah, i understand, but how? $text = ... what next?

Comment: Please search how to use php arrays and object.